# Pandas filter multi index based on statistic

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `res` with the following structure:

```
    Field   A   B
Security    date        
EFA 
2001-08-17  NaN 29.4944
2001-08-20  0.1983  29.5529
2001-08-21  -0.2374 29.4827
2001-08-22  1.2297  29.8453
2001-08-23  -0.4702 29.7049
2001-08-24  1.3622  30.1096
2001-08-27  -0.1787 30.0558
2001-08-28  -1.1440 29.7119
2001-08-29  -0.4566 29.5763
2001-08-30  -1.4235 29.1553
2001-08-31  0.2407  29.2254
2001-09-04  -2.2809 28.5588
2001-09-05  -0.6143 28.3834
2001-09-06  -2.2662 27.7402
2001-09-07  -0.5902 27.5765
2001-09-10  -1.1450 27.2607
2001-09-17  -4.3758 26.0678
2001-09-18  -0.8075 25.8573
2001-09-19  -0.2714 25.7872
2001-09-20  -4.3537 24.6644
2001-09-21  -2.7975 23.9745
2001-09-24  4.6341  25.0855
2001-09-25  1.1655  25.3778
2001-09-26  0.5069  25.5065
2001-09-27  1.5773  25.9088
2001-09-28  1.9500  26.4140
2001-10-01  -0.5402 26.2713
2001-10-02  0.3530  26.3641
2001-10-03  1.0218  26.6334
2001-10-04  1.0642  26.9169
```

And the following index:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'EFA', u'IVV', u'SPY'], [2001-01-02 00:00:00, 2001-01-03 00:00:00, 2001-01-04 00:00:00, 2001-01-05 00:00:00, 2001-01-08 00:00:00, 2001-01-09 00:00:00, 2001-01-10 00:00:00, 2001-01-11 00:00:00, 2001-01-12 00:00:00, 2001-01-16 00:00:00, 2001-01-17 00:00:00, 2001-01-18 00:00:00, 2001-01-19 00:00:00, 2001-01-22 00:00:00, 2001-01-23 00:00:00, 2001-01-24 00:00:00, 2001-01-25 00:00:00, 2001-01-26 00:00:00, 2001-01-29 00:00:00, 2001-01-30 00:00:00, 2001-01-31 00:00:00, 2001-02-01 00:00:00, 2001-02-02 00:00:00, 2001-02-05 00:00:00, 2001-02-06 00:00:00, 2001-02-07 00:00:00, 2001-02-08 00:00:00, 2001-02-09 00:00:00, 2001-02-12 00:00:00, 2001-02-13 00:00:00, 2001-02-14 00:00:00, 2001-02-15 00:00:00, 2001-02-16 00:00:00, 2001-02-20 00:00:00, 2001-02-21 00:00:00, 2001-02-22 00:00:00,...]],               names=[u'Security', u'date'])
```

And I want to filter where the mean of A is<0

So I am trying to do the following:

```
f = res.unstack(level=0)['A'].mean()<0
```

And I get:

```
Security
EFA    False
IVV    False
SPY    False
dtype: bool
```

Great!

Now when trying to go back to filter res on f I keep getting errors regardless of what I have tried.

It seems [slice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/advanced.html) may be the right route but I am unsure how to apply it properly.

Any input here would be hugefuly helpful!

I am a bit bound to this response object unfortunately.

Comment: fyi, changed the answer a little bit

Comment: @JohnE Thanks JohnE. To be honest I find the multi-index a quite messy when it comes to accessing the members. Why would one do this in a multi-index fashion? Is there something magical here I am missing?

Comment: LOL, I pretty much agree.  I tend to avoid MultiIndexes 95% of the time and consider this a good example of the "flat is better than nested" from zen of python.  Mainly I use along with stack/unstack.  There are other advantages but I couldn't describe them very well.  In any event, you're never more than a `reset_index()` away from a simple index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but there are 2 alternatives below.  The first one is probably the simplest way IMO (using groupby/transform) but the second one is probably closer (I think) to what you are asking for.

**Method 1** Create a variable corresponding to the mean of A and conform to your dataframe's index with transform:

```
>>> res['mean_A'] = res.groupby(level=0)['A'].transform('mean')

                          A        B   mean_A
security date                                
efa      2001-08-20  0.1983  29.5529 -0.07536
         2001-08-21 -0.2374  29.4827 -0.07536
         2001-08-22 -1.2297  29.8453 -0.07536
         2001-08-23 -0.4702  29.7049 -0.07536
         2001-08-24  1.3622  30.1096 -0.07536
ivv      2001-08-20  0.1983  29.5529  0.41652
         2001-08-21 -0.2374  29.4827  0.41652
         2001-08-22  1.2297  29.8453  0.41652
         2001-08-23 -0.4702  29.7049  0.41652
         2001-08-24  1.3622  30.1096  0.41652
```

Then standard boolean indexing is very easy:

```
>>> res[ res['mean_A'] < 0 ]

                          A        B   mean_A
security date                                
efa      2001-08-20  0.1983  29.5529 -0.07536
         2001-08-21 -0.2374  29.4827 -0.07536
         2001-08-22 -1.2297  29.8453 -0.07536
         2001-08-23 -0.4702  29.7049 -0.07536
         2001-08-24  1.3622  30.1096 -0.07536
```

**Method 2** Alternatively, if you are starting with 'f' and need to do it that way, you could approach it like this (note I'm using groupby instead of stack just because that's a more natural approach to me, but it doesn't matter):

```
>>> f = (res.groupby(level=0)['A'].mean() < 0)
>>> res[ res.reset_index()['security'].map(f).values ]

                          A        B
security date                       
efa      2001-08-20  0.1983  29.5529
         2001-08-21 -0.2374  29.4827
         2001-08-22 -1.2297  29.8453
         2001-08-23 -0.4702  29.7049
         2001-08-24  1.3622  30.1096
```